# Inferring arrow equality

Tags: category-theory

Suppose we have $u ; v ; w = id ; w$.  Is it right to say that we also have $u ; v = id$?

I thought that this is like Leibniz, but the implication seems to be the wrong way round.

Comment: Is "$;$" supposed to be composition of morphisms in the reverse order?

Comment: Yes. I think the semicolon is pronounced "then", as opposed to $\circ$ which is pronounced "after".

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no reason you can cancel $w$. If $w$ is a morphism to a terminal object, for instance, then the equation automatically holds for all possible choices.of $u,v$.

Comment: So, is that yes if $w$ is a map to a terminal, but not necessarily otherwise?

Comment: Read that again. If $w$ is a map to a terminal, then your equation is automatic-thus you can conclude nothing at all from it, certainly not that $u ; v$ is the identity.

Comment: You're a bit condescending, but thanks.

Comment: I don't find the answer "condescending": I would term it "very neat".

Comment: Well, thank you for your correction.

Comment: I believe saying "read that again" was unnecessary.  Perhaps just a friendly reminder of the uniqueness of maps to a terminal object would have been much "neater".  Plus, I haven't yet encountered the word "automatic" yet in my studies of category theory, and that might be the case for others, too.